# Python merge similar list values, from defined number of charactes to new list values

Tags: python, list, loops

I have already sorted and filtered list of files which look similar to this:

`sortList =  ['aa.001', 'aa.002', 'aa.003', 'vvv.001', 'vvv.002', 'vvv.003']`

and I would like to have new list with merged similar values before `.` as  independent lists inside list:

`merList = [['aa.001', 'aa.002', 'aa.003'], ['vvv.001', 'vvv.002', 'vvv.003']]`

I tried to make loop but without result, so will be great if anyone could help fix it:

```
merList = []
for name in sortList:
    temp_merList = []   
    for b in range(len(sortList)-1):
        if name[b][:-3] == name[b+1][:-3] and name[b] not in merList:
            temp_merList.append(name)
        else:
            merList.append(temp_merList)
print(merList)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

sortList =  ['aa.001', 'aa.002', 'aa.003', 'vvv.001', 'vvv.002', 'vvv.003']

out = []
for _, g in groupby(sortList, lambda k: k.split('.')[0]):
    out.append(list(g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['aa.001', 'aa.002', 'aa.003'], ['vvv.001', 'vvv.002', 'vvv.003']]
```

---

EDIT: Another method (using temporay dictionary):

```
sortList =  ['aa.001', 'aa.002', 'aa.003', 'vvv.001', 'vvv.002', 'vvv.003']

tmp = {}
for name in sortList:
    tmp.setdefault(name.split('.')[0], []).append(name)

merList = [v for _, v in tmp.items()]

print(merList)
```

Comment: This works fine, but to be curios, is there chance to do it with my former `for loop`?

Comment: @michal The inner loop looks "fishy" to me (why `temp_merList`?). Personally, I would use `itertools`. I also edited my question and put there version without itertools.